# Using DOM to get element id's inside onclick

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to access id's of elements fetched by `getElementsByTagName` but I'm getting an error：

```js
var divs=document.getElementsByTagName("div");
for(var i=0;i<divs.length;i++){
  divs[i].onclick=function(){
    alert(divs[i].id); 
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8" />
 <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="1">1</div>
 <div id="2">2</div>
 <div id="3">3</div>
 <div id="4">4</div>
 <div id="5">5</div>
 <div id="6">6</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The error is:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined

When I change

```js
alert(divs[i].id);
```

to

```js
alert(this.id);
```

it works, but I don't understand why this happens.

Comment: Within the click handler, **this** refers to the element clicked, and it no longer has a reference to the appropriate _i_

Comment: If you must use `alert(divs[i].id);`, try `for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) { (function(i) { divs[i].onclick = function () { alert(divs[i].id); } })(i); }`.

Comment: @akinuri   I get a new way to solve the problem , thank you!

Comment: @Jrd  I get it ,thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var divs=document.getElementsByTagName("div");
for(var i=0; i < divs.length;i++){
  divs[i].onclick=function(){
    alert(this.id); 
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8" />
 <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="1">1</div>
 <div id="2">2</div>
 <div id="3">3</div>
 <div id="4">4</div>
 <div id="5">5</div>
 <div id="6">6</div>
</body>
</html>
```

`this.id` works because:

After you added a `onclick` to the element, the element call the function if you click on the element.

After the loop, `i` will be increased to the length of the `divs` array (which is 6). And when the element is clicked and the function is called, `divs[6]` is undefined and you can't get id of undefined, while the function can understand `this` points to the clicked element and it will work.

Comment: thank you for your help ^_^    I add alert(i);  before alert(divs[i].id);  and test, it alerts 6, then I have a new qusetion : why I click <div id="1">1</div>the i=6 instead of 1?

Comment: @nian I tried to make it clear in my answer. `i` will be increased to the length of `divs` array, which is 6, after the loop / adding all `onclick` events on 6 divs. So **when you click on one of these elements, which is after the loop**, `i = 6` whichever element you clicked.

Comment: Sorry, my English may be poor and I wish I made myself understood.

Comment: I get it !  Thank you!